# How to handle recurring times?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

First off, I marked this question as language agnostic, but I'm using PHP and MySQL. It shouldn't affect the question itself very much tho.

I'm creating an application which shows times of certain shows throughout the week. Every single show is recurring (on weekly basis) and there might be shows which are airing through 2 days - eg. starting on Sunday at 23:30, ending on Monday at 00:30. I'm storing start of the show (day of the week - Monday, Tuesday... - it's never exact date; time) and duration. There are never shows that would take more than 24 hours.

My problem is with validation if newly added shows aren't overlapping some old ones. Especially if it comes to Sunday-Monday shows.

How are such recurring events usually handled on both DB side and server side?

**tl;dr version with stuff I considered**

My first idea was to create some custom validation algorithm, but it seemed too cumbersome and complicated. Not that I'd whine about complicated hand-made solutions, but I'm interested if there isn't something more basic that I'm missing.

Other alternative that came to mind was to change table structure to use datetime (instead of "day of week" and "time"), and use a fake fixed date range to store the data. For example all Mondays would be set to 5th Jan 1970, Sundays would use 11th Jan 1970. There would be one exception to this rule - if there would be some show which starts on Sunday and ends on Monday, it would be stored as 12th Jan 1970. This solution would allow more flexible quering of the DB than the original one, and it would also simplify queries for shows which overlap between individual weeks (since we can do the comparison directly in the query). There are some disadvantages to this solution as well (for one, using fake dates might make it confusing).

Both solutions smell of wrong algorithms to me and would love to hear some opinions from more experienced fellow developers.

Comment: So there can only be a single show at a given time and you're trying to validate if a new show is added there's no intersection with any existing show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you could just store the starting minute of each show as an integer number of minutes since the start of the week (10,080 possible values).

Then a show starting at minute `$a` with duration `$dur_a` will overlap `$b` if and only if

`(10080 + $b - $a) % 10080 < $dur_a`

For example consider a show starting at 11pm Sunday and another starting at 12.30am Monday. Here `$a == 10020` and `$dur_a == 120` and `$b == 30`. `(10080 + $b - $a) % 10080 == 90`. This is less than `$dur_a` and hence the shows overlap.

Comment: The main problem is when the show starts on Sunday evening and ends on Monday morning. You are not considering it in your example.

Comment: Why not? If `$a == 10020` and `$dur_a == 120` and `$b == 30`, then `(10080 + $b - $a) % 10080 == 90`. This is less than `$dur_a` and hence the shows overlap.

Comment: I found a flaw tho. If some old show starts at 0 and lasts 30 and I add show that starts at 10 and lasts 10, it still lets me add it. I'll need to fix it somehow.

Comment: In your example, `$a == 0`, `$dur_a == 30` and `$b == 10`. `(10080 + $b - $a) % 10080 == $b - $a == 10`. This is less than `$dur_a` and hence the shows overlap.

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be simplified by converting the data into a format that is amenable to the calculations that are required. I recommend creating a type that represents the start times as the number of minutes from Sunday at midnight. Then simple integer range comparisons could be used to find overlapping shows.

The internal representation must, of course, be hidden and abstracted. You may, at some point, want to change the representation from minutes to seconds, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for a custom validation algorithm:

- For each show, compute all showing intervals `[start1, end1], [start2, end2], ... [startN, endN]`, where N is the number of recurrence of the show.
- For a new show, also compute these intervals.
- Now check if any of these new intervals intersect any old intervals. This is the case if the start or the end of one interval is contained in the other.